# verify structure layout at build time

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-no-std

How can I verify the layout of a (`repr(C)`) structure without running the code?  E.g. when I have

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Registers {
    urxd:       u32,        // 0x00
    _rsrvd0:    [u32;15],
    utxd:       u32,        // 0x40
    _rsrvd1:    [u32;15],
    ucr1:       u32,        // 0x80
}
```

how can I make the build process fail when `ucr1` is not at positition 0x80 (e.g. due to miscalculated `_rsrvd` members or target depending padding)?

In C I would write something like

```c
struct foo {
    uint32_t    a;
    uint32_t    b;
    uint32_t    c;
    uint32_t    d;
};

static void _test() {
    _Static_assert(offsetof(struct foo, d) == 12);
}
```

For `_Static_assert` there seem to exist crates like `static_assertions` which implement hacks like these from the good old C times (negative array sizes and so).

But for `offsetof()` I have found only non-`const` implementations.

Code is for embedded platforms without `#[test]` support so I can not test it at runtime.   Running `#[test]` on a std-platform might give wrong results because padding/alignment is different there.

Comment: `static-assertions` is no longer needed since Rust 1.57. You can use `const _: () = assert!(...);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `const_field_offset` crate to get the offset and the `static_assertions` to assert during the build.

```
use const_field_offset;
use static_assertions as sa;

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(const_field_offset::FieldOffsets)]
struct Registers {
    urxd:       u32,        // 0x00
    _rsrvd0:    [u32;15],
    utxd:       u32,        // 0x40
    _rsrvd1:    [u32;15],
    ucr1:       u32,        // 0x80
}

sa::const_assert!(0x80 == Registers::FIELD_OFFSETS.ucr1.get_byte_offset());
```

When the assert fails, the error message isn't super helpful, but it does at least fail the build:

```
sa::const_assert!(0x79 == Registers::FIELD_OFFSETS.ucr1.get_byte_offset());
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `0_usize - 1_usize`, which would overflow
```